ESP8266 is stuck in an infinite socket.accept() loop, i guess?
Ive been working with my ESP8266 and have encountered an issue that seems to be coming from nowhere and being unsolvanle. At least - to me.
Basically I went on with this tutorial on building a simple server socket.
However my esp suddenly stopped allowing connections to itself. The code works normally until the line 23 of main.py:
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()

And simply stops working or moving ahead in the while loop. Its simply stuck in itself!
There are no error messages. AT least Thonny doesnt show any.
The funny part is - sometimes it does actually accept the connection. With all the same code and hardware and one of 100 tries maybe.
Ive tried to look up for a similar failure here, on stackoverflow and @Techtician has the same, I believe unsolved problem. (link to his post here)

An important part to prove there is a problem is to be sure that there are really no connection requests comming (TCP protocol -> SYN packets). Don't know what tools you have available on your system. Could you connect with a standard tool like netcat (nc)? Could you check the TCP communication with something like tcpdump?

@VPfB, thanks for the quick answer. Im an absolute newbud to this topic. I`ll learn about nc and tcpdump and report my results as soon as I can!

FYI: Any "tutorial" that does request = conn.recv(1024) without parsing for a complete request is wrong.  TCP is a simple byte stream and you have to check the return value of recv and ensure you have all the bytes of a complete message.  recv(n) can receive 1-n bytes or 0 on socket close.  99% of questions about [tag:sockets]...this is the problem.

@MarkTolonen, Thank you very much for your comment. As I already understood, I know too less about networking for now. As soon as I will, I will update my code to do exactly what you have told. Thank you!

Let's try and simplify the issue.
Use this simple echo client + server and report back the results.
be sure to replace <CONTROLLER_IP> with the controller's ip address.
the server should be run on the controller,
the client - on your pc.
server:
import socket
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connection from client", addr)    
data = conn.recv(1024)
while data:    
    conn.sendall(data.decode().upper().encode())
    data = conn.recv(1024)
s.close()

client:
import socket

HOST = '<CONTROLLER_IP>'
PORT = 5000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print(f"Connected to server {HOST}:{PORT}")
    while True:
        msg = input("Type Message:") # type some text and hit enter
        s.sendall(msg.encode())
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('GOT: ', data.decode())


It is crucial to run the server before running the client,
otherwise the client's attempt to connect will surely fail.
As vpfb mentioned, a TCP connection is created.
until a connection is created, that s.accept() is blocking. that is a feature, not a bug.

Hi! Thanks for a quick response!
The results are:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 5, in 
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'exit'

my bad. with calls __exit__ but it doesn't exist in micropython. fixed

Not a problem) So, the result is, that now nothing happens. I launched the client in VSCode and server on ESP using Thonny. The y both were started. But neither of programs gave any result
[EDITED] The VS code gave next response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Working\Desktop\import socket.py", line 7, in 
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Interesting. This could be caused by many reasons. Can you go ahead and run ping <CONTROLLER_IP>?

It no reply returns, run arp -aand search for the controllers ip. Is it there? Is it possible the controller's ip has changed via dhcp? (on linux / mac the command is different, are you on windows?)

yeap. I am using windows (unluckly)

I see. Did you run the ping and arp?

Hi, sorry for long response. Ive tried to but it didnt bring anything. I suppose its just some kind of limitation my dad put on our wifi, as suddenly everything works perfect when I use my mobile Hotspot.

so, the arp doesnt find an adress of the controller. and ping writes Destination host unreachable.. Nevertheless, its: Ping statistics for ***********:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

i see. try pinging any other device (except the router). does it show up on the arp table?

Nope. I suppose my dad activated Router function that isolates devices from each other

ALright, it seems to be some kind of internal failure of my home WiFi-Router. Because we got it split in some sub networks, it fails to route devices inside of one network BUT does it perfectly in the other one. Really strange to me and to my father. After switching to other network managed by the same FritzBox it just started working perfectly. If I will find out some day the exact reason to why this happened - ill make an update
